# Cloning a element and setting state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a clone button in React, I have a state with an array that has 2 items in it. The button will send the index of the element selected, in this case let's say index 0. :) I can't get the following code to work

```
elements = [
    { item: 'something1', another: 'something2' },
    { item: 'something1', another: 'something2' }
];

setState( { 
    elements: [
        ...elements.slice( 0, index ),
        {
            ...elements[ index ],
            item: 'something'
        },
        ...elements.slice( index + 1 )
    ]
} )
```

I know I'm doing something wrong, but...

Comment: You [need to use the callback version of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), but although it's important you make that change, it's probably not the problem you're running into. There isn't enough above for us to figure out what the problem is, though. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: Separately, using an index is likely to be problematic when state updates stack up. Would be much better to use a unique identifier on the object itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `index + 1` in the 1st [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) call because you want to get all items up to and including the item you clone (slice stops before the `end` index), insert the clone, and add all other items after it:

```js
const elements = [
    { item: 'something1', another: 'something1' },
    { item: 'something2', another: 'something2' },
    { item: 'something3', another: 'something3' }
];

const index = 1;

const newElements = [
  ...elements.slice(0, index + 1),
  {
    ...elements[index],
    item: 'new something !!!'
  },
  ...elements.slice(index + 1)
];

console.log(newElements);
```

Comment: Ah, yes, they did say clone, not update. @TitelDoe - Comments on the question still apply.

Answer (score 0):

[Ori Drori's quite correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49759476/157247) about why the cloning isn't working. But there are two other issues with the code you'll want to address:

1. When setting state based on existing state, you [**must** use the callback version of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) since state updates can be stacked and are asynchronous. So not:

   ```
   this.setState({
       elements: [/*...*/]
   });
   ```

   but instead:

   ```
   this.setState(prevState => {
       return {
           elements: [/*...*/]
       };
   });
   ```
2. Partially because of #1 above, using the index is unreliable; other changes may have altered the array (your element may not even be in it anymore). Use the element itself. For instance, if your click handler is `cloneClick`, you'd use `onClick={this.cloneClick.bind(this, el)}` on the button to pass the element to the handler.

Here's a complete example:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      elements: [
          { item: 'item1', another: 'something1' },
          { item: 'item2', another: 'something2' }
      ]
    };
  }
  
  cloneClick(el) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const index = prevState.elements.indexOf(el);
      if (index === -1) {
        return null;
      }
      return {
        elements: [
          ...prevState.elements.slice(0, index + 1),
          {
            ...el,
            item: el.item + " (copy)"
          },
          ...prevState.elements.slice(index + 1)
        ]
      };
      // Alternately, this is more efficient:
      /*
      let clone = null;
      const elements = [];
      prevState.elements.forEach(prevEl => {
        elements[elements.length] = prevEl;
        if (prevEl === el) {
          elements[elements.length] = clone = {
            ...el,
            item: el.item + " (copy)"
          };
        }
      });
      return clone ? {elements} : null; // No update if the el wasn't found
      */
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.state.elements.map((el, i) =>
        <div key={i}>
          {el.item}
          -
          {el.another}
          <input type="button" value="Clone" onClick={this.cloneClick.bind(this, el)} />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```